# How to delete extraneous routes?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I ran `rake routes` and discovered a lot of routes that are NOT in my routes.rb file:

```
          home_index GET    /home(.:format)                              home#index
                     POST   /home(.:format)                              home#create
            new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)                          home#new
           edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format)                     home#edit
                home GET    /home/:id(.:format)                          home#show
                     PUT    /home/:id(.:format)                          home#update
                     DELETE /home/:id(.:format)                          home#destroy
```

I manually deleted the files that were created on generating a scaffold, but don't know how to fully clean up the mess of that test.

In my routes.rb file, I have:

```
  # define the root
  root :to => "home#about"

  # define all the possible routes from the home controller
  resources :home do
    get "about"
    get "create_subscription"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails creates a lot of default routes for anything declared with 'resources'. You can get around this by using ':only =>' in your routes file. See sections 2.2 and 4.6 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web.